# onCreate being called again when navigating away from Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, oncreate

Code works great. However, I am seeing something strange from an Activity Lifecycle perspective. The onCreate code basically sets the adapters to the relevant GridView and pulls items from a database and populates said GridView. Each item can be tapped by the user that will push the item's "playerId" to HubActivity.

The below is my **onCreate** code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Const.err("##> Running PlayerSearchActivity.onCreate");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_playersearch);
    this.mPlayerSearchBtn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.playerSearchButton);
    this.mPlayerSearchText=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.playerSearchText);
    this.mPlayerSearchGridView=(GridView) findViewById(R.id.psearch_playersearchgrid);
    this.mSavedPlayersGridView=(GridView) findViewById(R.id.psearch_savedplayersgrid);
    mPlayerSearchBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    this.savedPlayersAdapter = new PlayerGridAdapter(this);
    mSavedPlayersGridView.setAdapter(savedPlayersAdapter);
    mSavedPlayersGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,long arg3) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HubActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(Keys._PLAYERID,savedPlayersAdapter.getItemPlayerId(position));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    Const.err("<## Completed PlayerSearchActivity.onCreate");

}
```

I was curious about how each method was being called so I applied some logging around the functions (Const.err). The results are strange:

```
03-04 00:29:50.942:  ##> Running PlayerSearchActivity.onCreate
03-04 00:29:50.982:  <## Completed PlayerSearchActivity.onCreate
03-04 00:29:50.982:  ##> Running PlayerSearchActivity.onResume
03-04 00:29:51.058:  <## Completed PlayerSearchActivity.onResume

---Clicked item---

03-04 00:29:54.718:  ##> Running PlayerSearchActivity.onCreate
03-04 00:29:54.730:  <## Completed HubActivity.onCreate
..
```

Firstly, why is onCreate being called after I click an item? Also, I expected to see a "Completed PlayerSearchActivity.onCreate" message but this never occurrs.

Comment: Are you getting same log every time you run the app? I can see that just after your PlayerSearchActivity started, you got "Completed PlayerSearchActivity.onCreate". Also since the messages are async so you may not get them in correct sequence at times. Try putting break point and see the control. Also with break points log should be in proper sequence.

Comment: @Sushil - Yes I am getting this exact same log every time I run it. Yes, I am expecting a message 'Completed PlayerSearchActivity.onComplete' at the bottom of that log but it never happens! Clearly something is strange as we have 2 'Running' messages and only 1 'Completed' message. I will look into break points and see if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a copy-paste error, check your HubActivity.onCreate(), if you didn't paste by accident

```
Const.err("##> Running PlayerSearchActivity.onCreate");
```

instead of

```
Const.err("##> Running HubActivity.onCreate");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the problem. I did check this multiple times (having made this mistake before). Strange little issue I'm running into here..

Comment: You can try to add Const.err("##> Content set in PlayerSearchActivity.onCreate"); just after setContentView(R.layout.activity_playersearch); and see if it prints out?